# MySQL Calculate the sum of four different columns under two different grouping

Tags: group-by, sum, subquery, where-clause

I am trying to calculate total purchases in USD and LRD, and total sales in USD and LRD

I have a table in my datable called wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales, which has the following columns: id, goods, quantity, quantity_unit, price, currency, purpose, client_or_vendor, date; and in this query I am only concern about goods, price, currency, purpose,

The **currency** column is divided into two sub_categories, USD and LRD, and the **purpose** column has two sub-categories, 1 for purchases, and 2 for sales.

Now I want to find the sum of each goods purchased in usd, purchased in lrd, sold in usd, sold in lrd.

Here is the query
`SELECT wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales.`goods`, (SELECT SUM(wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales.`price`) as usd_price_purchased WHERE wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales.`purpose `= 1 and wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales.`currency `= 'USD') as usd_purchases, (SELECT SUM(wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales.`price`) as lrd_price_purchased WHERE wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales.`purpose `= 1 and wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales.`currency `= 'LRD') as lrd_purchases, (SELECT SUM(wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales.`price`) as usd_price_purchased WHERE wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales.`purpose `= 2 and wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales.`currency `= 'USD') as usd_sales, (SELECT SUM(wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales.`price`) as lrd_price_purchased WHERE wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales.`purpose `= 2 and wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales.`currency `= 'LRD') as lrd_sales FROM wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales GROUP BY wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales.`goods``

In the image, I expect under the usd_purchases column, the total usd purchased for each goods should be calculated, and like wise for the lrd_purchases, usd_sales, and lrd_sales, and should all be on the same row, but if they are all on the same row, the calculation is not correct
[Total usd and lrd goods sold and purchases for each goods miscalculated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx6wD.png)

and if the calculation should be correct, them I have to add **wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales.`purpose`, wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales.`currency`** to the group by, that is **GROUP BY wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales.`goods`, wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales.`purpose`, wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales.`currency`**, but then they won't be in the same line, like the image below
[Total usd and lrd goods sold and purchases for each goods correctly calculated, but not on the same row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGCcM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement, I understand that you want to aggregate your data by goods and get the total purchases and sales for both USD and LRD for each goods in separate columns.

Your query has a mistake, in using nested SELECT statements to calculate individual sums for each condition. Instead, we should use conditional aggregation to achieve this.

Here's a revised query:

```
SELECT 
goods,
SUM(CASE WHEN purpose = 1 AND currency = 'USD' THEN price ELSE 0 END) AS usd_purchases,
SUM(CASE WHEN purpose = 1 AND currency = 'LRD' THEN price ELSE 0 END) AS lrd_purchases,
SUM(CASE WHEN purpose = 2 AND currency = 'USD' THEN price ELSE 0 END) AS usd_sales,
SUM(CASE WHEN purpose = 2 AND currency = 'LRD' THEN price ELSE 0 END) AS lrd_sales
```

FROM
wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales
GROUP BY
goods;

Comment: Hi Mashrur Ayon, thanks a lot, that does it. I actually thought it was the end of the world for me, but thank you very much, I can now continue what I am doing.

Also please allow me to ask you this, "Is there any performance difference in using SELECT wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales.`goods` FROM wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales and SELECT goods FROM wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales", 

would you recommend one over the other? If so, then which would you recommend. 

Once again thank you very much

Comment: Hello JoseLawrence,

The queries you provided differ in the way they reference the column(s) they're selecting from the table:

SELECT wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales.goods FROM wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales
SELECT goods FROM wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales
In terms of performance, there's no difference between the two queries. They both achieve the same result and will have the same performance characteristics.

Comment: The primary reason to use the table name (or alias) in the SELECT clause, as done in the first query, is for clarity when dealing with joins or multi-table queries. If you're selecting columns from multiple tables and there's a possibility of column name overlap, then specifying the table name can disambiguate which column you're referring to.

Comment: `SELECT a.goods, b.goods `
`FROM wp_wpdt_clients_purchases_n_sales AS a`
`JOIN another_table AS b ON a.id = b.id`